# Cannot open database "aspnetdb" requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication

I am able to login and browse with my login name. But as soon as I press a hyperlink on my page it throws this:

```
Cannot open database "aspnetdb" requested by the login. The login failed.
```

Login failed for user 'DIMA-00AA1DA557\Dima'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "aspnetdb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'DIMA-00AA1DA557\Dima'.

Why does it do it/...

I think everything is okay with my connection string and membership provider:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <clear />
  <add name="LocalSqlServer" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI; Initial Catalog=aspnetdb" /> 
  <add name="YourGuruDB" connectionString="Data Source=DIMA-00AA1DA557;Initial Catalog=model;Integrated Security=True"/>
  <add name="modelConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='D:\Documents and Settings\Dima\My Documents\Visual Studio 2010\WebSites\WebSite10\App_Data\ASPNETDB.MDF';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;Trusted_Connection=Yes;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name=".MyCookie"
           loginUrl="~/Registration.aspx"
           protection="All"
           timeout="30" path="/" >
      <credentials passwordFormat="MD5">
        <user name="user" password="ca064d0730abfeb09e383a0e82e65f73"/>
      </credentials>
    </forms>
  </authentication>

  <roleManager enabled="true"/>

  <membership defaultProvider="MyMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear/>
      <add name="MyMembershipProvider"
           type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
           connectionStringName="modelConnectionString"
           minRequiredPasswordLength="1"
           minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
           enablePasswordReset="true"
           maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="1000"
           passwordAttemptWindow="4000"
           enablePasswordRetrieval="true"
           requiresUniqueEmail="false"
           passwordFormat="Encrypted"
           applicationName="/WebSite10" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
```

Comment: I think it's had something to do with file permission under "documents and settings". Try moving your ASP.NET to some another place (like C:\) to see if your website works or not.

Comment: How do i fix this? why does it take the "dima" name, i have never logged in/registered with that name.. how do i prevent dima name from being used and the logged in user name be used instead?

Comment: Thom, if i would rather make it be inside the visual studio projects with the rest of the files...

Comment: @Dmitry it takes the dima name because you use integrated authentication and Fyns the site under those credentials. To use the Web site user you'd need to impersonate however that is likely a bad idea and you should use SQL server authentication with a specific user instead

Comment: ooh, i think i understand what you mean. So my only solution is to go to the server explorer, right click, modify connection, authenticate with SQL, and then put that new connection string into my web.config and use it :!?!?!?!

Comment: That's one way to get the connection string. Refer to http://www.connectionstrings.com/ for a complete reference of connection string.

Comment: @Dimitry Makovetskiyd - Nope, see my answer, I believe the problem is caused by the fact you've got two connection strings pointing to different databases called `aspnetdb` and an unconfigured role provider using the default (incorrect) database.

Comment: so from the 3 above which one should i remove? i dont need the LocalSqlServer connection string. but when i remove it there is a sign of it in the machine.config. how do i remove it from there?

Comment: lol..removed it from the machine.config and web.config..now it seems to work well

Comment: You don't really need to remove it from the machine config, as that's what the `<clear />` directive does - it removes all previously defined connection strings in the config hierarchy for this application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As "Rune FS" points out in the comments, you've configured your Database Connection Strings to use Integrated Authentication, which is a good thing, because you're not storing explicit usernames/passwords in your config files.

However, you need to be aware of where it's getting the "integrated" credentials from - in this instance, the credentials of the user that IIS (or the VS Dev Server) is running under are used to connect to the database - if it's using your Windows login name, I assume you're using either IIS Express or the VS Devevelopment Server?

I believe the problem you've got is that while you've enabled the role manager, you haven't configured it, and you've left the default `LocalSqlServer` connection string enabled also pointing to a database called `aspnetdb` - by default this will attempt to use the default role manager provider, which uses the LocalSqlServer connection.

Modify the `<rolemanager />` element to read:

```
<rolemanager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MyRoleProvider" >
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyRoleProvider" 
         applicationName="/" 
         connectionStringName="modelConnectionString"
         type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" />
  </providers>
</rolemanager>
```

I'd also recommend removing the `LocalSqlServer` connection string if you're not using it to avoid this sort of confusion.

Comment: Ben thanks you helped a lot, as i pointed out i removed the whole mess from teh web config and machine.config. Where do i put hte rolemanager code? (it shows me a blue line under the rolemanager tag above!).. Can i safely edit the users role with WAT..will all my settings be added to rolemanager?

Answer (score 1):

That Windows user isn't allowed to connect to that database and use it.

Check to make sure:

that you have the proper server name in your connection string. Is it really localhost? Or did you perhaps install SQL Server Express and it ended up being (local)\SQLExpress instead??

that the server you're connecting to has a login for Philip-Desktop\Philip (check in Object Explorer -> (your server) -> Security -> Logins)

that the database ASPNETDB has a user based on that login so that you can use that database (check in Object Explorer -> (your server) -> Databases -> (your database) -> Security -> Users)

that your admin.aspx page is truly referencing that connection string you've given (WIJLConnectionString1). Is there by any chance a separate web.config in your Admin folder that e.g. has a different connection string, and the admin.aspx page references that connection string instead??

Answer (score 0):

First check that the SQL Server has mixed mode authentication turned on. Then create a SQL login and assign it as a database user. Once you have done that you can put those credentials in the connection string and take out the trusted security option.

Comment: A bit of convoluted way to achieve what i achieved already..But nice to know that there is an alternative solution

Comment: Glad you got it sorted, but I would hardly call five steps convoluted.